# Deis Workflow support for non-12-factor services

Tags: mysql, postgresql, redis, paas, deis

I use Deis Workflow, which is an open source Platform as a Service (PaaS) that makes it easy to deploy and manage applications on our servers.

I understand twelve-factor is the main guideline for Deis Workflow, but is it possible to use it to create services like Postgres, Redis or MySQL?

Some other PaaS services e.g. Dokku and Flynn allow users to create services and link them to the app containers.

Is there a way to acheive the same result in Deis Workflow?

Answer (score 1):

I'm an engineer at Deis, formerly from the Workflow team, and still occasionally involved in it. Great question. As it seems you already caught on to, Workflow is (currently) hyper-focused on 12factor applications. Generally, what we have said is that anyone wishing to do anything more complex than that may wish to "fall back" on "plain Kubernetes," but that doesn't have to be as painful as it might sound when you take [Helm](http://helm.sh/) into account. Helm is the Kubernetes package manager (and is another Deis product). Helm 2 just went GA today, in fact. It's easy to create your own Helm charts (packages), but even better than that, many charts already exist for common things like Postgres, Redis, and MySQL (all examples you gave). Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

I am Anton - one of the maintainers of Hephy, the open source fork of Deis Workflow. https://github.com/teamhephy

Deis Workflow was originally designed with hyper focus on 12-factor apps and deploying them. We don't see any major changes to that in the coming few months except the possibility to define multiple services per application namespaces. See this PR: https://github.com/teamhephy/controller/pull/71

Aside from all of this, we hope to integrate other services that provide DBaaS (Databases as a Service) and do some blog posts on how to use Hephy Workflow and those services together for a common solution.